# How to make a flexible-height modal with fixed header

Tags: css, modal-dialog

I've created a really simple modal that allows the content to decrease or expand without running off the page - always leaving 10% margin on the top and bottom. When the page isn't tall enough to contain all the modal content, the entire modal becomes scrollable.

[See jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZX895/)

Is it possible, using only CSS, to replicate this behavior but only have the modal body be scrollable, so the header is always fixed. I've tried a few things, but haven't come up with the solution yet. Making the header `position: fixed` almost works, I have to reposition it over the modal box and then try to add padding to the body so the content is visible under the header, which doesn't budge the scrollbars down. I always prefer to exhaust all the css alternatives before I bind some js to window resize and manually manipulate the body height.

Comment: On a minor note, you can replace the 3 paragraph CSS rules with the following (which is more compact, and supports more versions of IE) `p + p {margin-top: 1em;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Applying the `max-height` and `overflow-y` settings to `.body` rather than to `.wrap`...?</s>

**Edit 1:**

Nothing's turned up so far within the constraints, which suggests either JavaScript or straying from the constraints (using % for the header height <s>or px margins</s>).

**Edit 2:**

Here's an [initial demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/Nae9Z/1/) using % for the header height. I added a px `min-height` to the header tag to prevent the header from almost disappearing on very small screens, at the expense of the top margin (which is reduced on very small screens).

On a screen >= 400px tall, it should work exactly as per the requirements (40px header with 10% height). If the header were reduced in height, it would support slightly-smaller screens (a 30px header with 10% height would support >= 300px screens). Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/Nae9Z/3/) with a 30px header.

It's a clumsy solution, but it's the only one that turned up without using JavaScript.

Also, note that I added an `h2` and a `.content` tag and moved the `padding:10px;` there, to avoid combining % height and padding in the same elements (which leads to a taller height than the % value specified).

Comment: Nope. The modal doesn't adhere to the height contraints - http://jsfiddle.net/ZX895/2/

Comment: The closest to a CSS solution that comes to mind is if you can live with top and bottom margins in px (rather than %), or a header height in % (rather than auto or px). Then there's no longer a need to combine % and px for the heights, and it may become much easier to solve.

Comment: I was forgetting that since the height has to be in %, the margins pretty much have to be as well. So the only way to really simplify this is to use % for everything rather than px, including for the header height. But a % header height might look very bad on very large or very small screens. If you could live with a % height for the header, I still think it's doable in CSS. But that's a huge IF.

Comment: Right. Beginning to think that I'm going to need to use some js for this.

Comment: I added a demo to the answer above, using % height and px min-height for the header. It isn't pretty, but see what you think :)

Comment: Yeah, the variable header kind of kills it for me. Thanks for taking a real stab at it though. I'll give you the accepted answer since, even though it's not pretty, it comes the closest to replicating the behavior with only css. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This might be late, but I had to solve a similar issue of fixed header, fluid height, fluid width.

This is how I tackled the issue:

- Give your elements a border-box box-sizing. Use a wrapper to center and create a bounding box. This can be a fluid one with min-width and max-width + percentages.
- Give your content element an overflow-y of auto and a max-height of 100%;
- Use box-sizing:border-box;

The complete code should be something like this:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
.wrap {
   position: relative;
   margin: 0 auto;
   display: block;
   width: 90%;
    /* Change the max-width value on a media query breakpoint to make this example more "responsive" */ 
    max-width: 500px;
    height: 90%;
    padding: 30px;
}
.modal header {
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #007;
}
.modal .body {
    background-color: #FFF;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mariomc/EhR7r/